# iOS in-app purchases sandbox environment

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I am having problem while testing my **in-app purchases**,because when I test,I am getting this error message :- `Verification Required: before you can make purchases, you must verify your payment info [Environment: Sandbox]`.

Two buttons are presented in **UIAlertView** that are **:cancel** and **continue**..and when I tap on 'continue' button,i am redirected to safari and I follow verification steps,but then also I am getting '**Cancelled transaction**' event.

Can any one suggest what to do? Any help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Any luck with figuring this out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some Advice for inAp purchase test

1. Not works in simulator.
2. You need to sign out from Store option in ur device to test inAp
3. InAp purchase product Id, TestUserId, Bundle Ids - should be from same developer account.

Comment: i followed all steps but am still getting `response.products=nil`. what to do now...??